# How can I fetch data from the firestore and use it as variables in the widget tree?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(peRcent());
}

class peRcent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _peRcentState createState() => _peRcentState();
}


String R = '100';

class _peRcentState extends State<peRcent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[200],
          title: Text('Tracking'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user0').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final index = snapshot.data.documents.length();
              DocumentSnapshot daTa = snapshot.data.documents[index];
              var Xl = daTa['level'];
              return CircularPercentIndicator(
                animation: true,
                radius: 110.0,
                lineWidth: 10.0,
                percent: Xl / 100,
                center: new Text(
                  "$R %",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                progressColor: Colors.green,
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I got is "The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents" and "Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: documents"## Heading ##
I want the variables to be updated via the latest document in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of Firestore. If you are following an online tutorial, `documents` has been deprecated, and now you should use `docs` instead.

Also, after you modify this change `documents => docs`, you will get another error, because you are writing this :

```
 final index = snapshot.data.documents.length();
 DocumentSnapshot daTa = snapshot.data.documents[index];
```

what you are doing here is assigning an int value to index, and this value will be the length of the list, which is equal to the number of retrieved documents. In other words, if you retrieve 10 documents, the value of `index` will be `=10`.

Also, change `DocumentSnapshot` into this ==>  `QueryDocumentSnapshot` in the second line of your code. Because every document youa re getting back is a result of a query, thus, `QueryDocumentSnapshot`.

When you say `snapshot.data.docs[index]`, this will throw an error, because the length of documents is ==10, but the index of the last document in this list is actually 9.

So, your code should look like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user0').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      final index = snapshot.data!.docs.length;
      QueryDocumentSnapshot daTa = snapshot.data!.docs[index-1];
      var Xl = daTa['level'];
//the rest of your code
```

Comment: Yes I only want to fetch data from the last document and I still get the same errors.

Comment: @Innova change `DocumentSnapshot` into this ==>  `QueryDocumentSnapshot`

Comment: @Innova Edited answer, how your streambuilder should look.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, case closed.

Comment: You're most welcome! Kindly consider marking it as an answer to your question and upvoting the useful comments for overcoming your problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy try in this way I hope this would be helpful

StreamBuilder(

```
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection("userprofile")
                  .document(userid)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }

                var Profiledetail = snapshot.data;
             
                print(github);
                return Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Row(children: [
                    ClipOval(
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: Profiledetail["profileimageurl"],
                            height: 150,
                            width: 150,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover)),])}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved it thanks to the previous comment.